# My-SQL will not start or restart

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, mysql

Hi i have created a virtual machine with the **ubuntu server 16.04** and my apache and PHP work fine but **My-SQL** will not start. The following errors appears in the **/var/log/mysql/error.log** directory

```
    2019-05-29T22:48:38.283258Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentat$
    2019-05-29T22:48:38.936466Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
    2019-05-29T22:48:39.102231Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
    2019-05-29T22:48:39.206991Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new U$
    2019-05-29T22:48:39.210030Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
    2019-05-29T22:48:39.216051Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
    2019-05-29T22:53:51.167747Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
    2019-05-29T22:53:51.205638Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
    2019-05-29T22:53:51.670354Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentat$
    2019-05-29T22:53:51.707776Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.11-0ubuntu6) starting as process 883 ...
    2019-05-29T22:53:53.009360Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
    2019-05-29T22:53:53.009492Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    2019-05-29T22:53:53.009513Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2019-05-29T22:53:53.009528Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
    2019-05-29T22:53:53.009542Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
    2019-05-29T22:53:53.009556Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    2019-05-29T22:53:53.022961Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    2019-05-29T22:53:53.081906Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
    2019-05-29T22:53:53.113682Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
    2019-05-29T22:53:53.161282Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2019-05-29T22:53:53.181194Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
    2019-05-29T22:53:53.332127Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    2019-05-29T22:53:54.129948Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
    2019-05-29T22:53:54.130213Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
    2019-05-29T22:53:54.251764Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    2019-05-29T22:53:54.253404Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
    2019-05-29T22:53:54.253458Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
    2019-05-29T22:53:54.310131Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.11 started; log sequence number 2492906
    2019-05-29T22:53:54.310493Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
    2019-05-29T22:53:54.310726Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    2019-05-29T22:53:55.001578Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
    2019-05-29T22:53:55.001659Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
    2019-05-29T22:53:55.001686Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
    2019-05-29T22:53:55.001728Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
    2019-05-29T22:53:55.573747Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190530  0:53:55
    2019-05-29T22:53:56.501560Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
    2019-05-29T22:53:56.502122Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
    Version: '5.7.11-0ubuntu6'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
    2019-05-29T22:53:56.574990Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    2019-05-30T11:02:36.364794Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
    2019-05-30T11:02:36.365058Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
```

I am new to ubuntu and i have no idea what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your error is: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`. Everything else seems unrelevant to me.

Comment: How would i go about fixing this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `sudo` command when logging in to mysql? Like `sudo mysql -u root -p`.

Comment: Hi @Edper i have yes and i get the following error  Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run                                                                                        /mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: My sql service won't even let me start it

Comment: Try to find the location of your file where the mysql socket is and then change file permission. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq)